# How to check format date python

Tags: python

I want to chack data format if in english or frensh. I did this code below, but it find the format engilsh and not the format french. When I reverse the order of the check it find the format french and not the format english. 
I think it check the first if, once it find a result it quit the program.

When I reverse the order of the if and elif I got frensh date correct. 
How can check the both dates in if and elif ?

Thank you

Comment: This code cannot determine the language for the first 12 days out of *any* month.

Comment: @usr2564301 sorry I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: You can't. For some dates it is obvious what format they are - namely, only a day can be 13 or higher. However, if both day and month are 12 or lower, there's no way to tell. For example, 07/04/2020 might be 4th July (D/M/Y) or 7th April (M/D/Y). Besides, M/D/Y is American, not English. And D/M/Y is used in almost all of Europe.

Comment: @Błotosmętek thanks for your answer, could you help me please ?

Comment: Help HOW? As I said, this problem CAN'T BE SOLVED.

Comment: but I put the format in clause if , normally should find it

Comment: @Błotosmętek American or English the same

Comment: Did it raise a ValueError? Is that the problem?

Comment: @SergioR Yes I got an Valueerror: time date 29/12/2019 does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

Comment: When I run the clause if separately, and I return the best date matches to the format I got always a result but when I run the clauses if, elif, I enable them I got always an error in the second one.

Comment: Look at `dateutil`: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html. It has a parser that will do what you want, and the parser has a `daysfirst` parameter that you can set to deal with dates that are ambiguous, like 12/1/2021 (is that 12 January or 1 December?). In some cases, as  @Błotosmętek says, you have no choice but to guess, unless you have some other information to go on. And American and English are *not* the same. Only Americans put the month first. Knowing that might help when you have to guess.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

> ValueError is raised if the date_string and format can’t be parsed by time.strptime() or if it returns a value which isn’t a time tuple. For a complete list of formatting directives, see strftime() and strptime() Behavior.

Your code is bound to parse an invalid format at some point so obviously it's going to raise a ValueError. You either modify the code with a `try/except ValueError`, something like:

```
try:
    time.strptime(match, '%m/%d/%Y')
    print("Data in english")
except ValueError:
    print("Data in french")
```

which it may not look too neat. But this code will pass invalid date as french so you would need to nest another try/except ValueError (yuck!)

The other option would be to parse manually the first two numbers (day/month) and check which one is above 12. Whichever method you choose you will always have problems deciding if 01/02/2021 is Febraury 1st or January 2nd